# Type '{ |cssProperties|}' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>' in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I have this code:

```
const linkStyle = {
 color: '#8954A8',
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 fontSize: 16,
 verticalAlign: '5%',
};

const IndexPage: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
 return (
    <>       
     <a style={linkStyle} href={`${link.url}?utm_source=starter&utm_medium=start-page&utm_campaign=minimal-starter`}>link </a>
    </>  
}
```

I am getting this problem:

> Type '{ color: string; fontWeight: string; fontSize: number; verticalAlign: string;
> }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(1842, 9): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared
> here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes,
> HTMLAnchorElement>'

how can fix it and why is the reason of my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little mismatch in typing of TypeScript. You would need to add `CSSProperties` interface for the style object.

```
import { CSSProperties } from "react";

const linkStyle: CSSProperties = {
  color: "#8954A8",
  fontWeight: "bold",
  fontSize: 16,
  verticalAlign: "5%"
};
```

Working Sample:

[image: Edit React typescript custom inline style]

Comment: This was the solution that worked, interestingly neither the linting nor copilot picked up on the solution.